# Run a Stored procedure in c# from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to load the main.usp_setup procedure found in the SQL file. It is a procedure to open an XML file and I am passing the filename as a parameter in the method. For some reason it is not loading correctly. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
public static bool loadXml(string filename)
    {
        bool load = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constConn);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("main.usp_setup", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000).Value = filename;
            int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            load = true;

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An Exception Occured: " + e.ToString());
        }
        return load;
    }
```

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé In the c# the program is not finding my procedure from the sql so loads of errors are popping up

Comment: Is the InitialCatalog of your connection string set to the correct database?

Comment: Show the error message please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("main.usp_setup", conn) { 
                       CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@file", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000).Value = filename;
        int rows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        load = true;
}
```

Instead of this:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constConn);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("main.usp_setup", conn);
    try{
        conn.Open();
```

Comment: What is the actual difference?